# Vertical grid lines in Matplotlib on specific locations

Tags: python, matplotlib, gridlines

I am trying to draw vertical lines (grid lines) on the chart on specific locations on the x-axis using Matplotlib. However, my axis does not have integer/number as ticks but strings. And I would like to distinguish the bar graphs drawn on the two ticks separately.

[image]

For example in the chart, I would like to have minor/major vertical grid lines to separate bars on point A, B, C and D.

[image]

So far, I have only been able to find solutions where the x-axis has numbers/integers in a certain sequence and that does not help in solving my problem!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is the data, the code? It's hard to help without having anything to help with

Comment: It might be worth reading about [mcve]s

Comment: You may treat the axis just as a normal numeric axes. `A` is at location `0`, `B` at `1` etc. Hence producing a minor grid at locations 0.5, 1.5, etc can be done as usual.